# Disable automatic cluster repair on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Every time I create a new node pool on GKE, the cluster becomes unresponsive for several minutes, while the Cloud Console displays

> > Repairing cluster.
> >     The values shown below are going to change soon.

I've set `Management.AutoRepair: false` and `Management.AutoUpgrade: false` on the node pools, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on this issue.

Comment: How large of a node pool are you creating? If you add enough nodes all at once, the master will need to resize which will cause the cluster to become unresponsive

Comment: @PatrickW oh interesting, I didn't know that! Is there a link to the documentation for that? The node pools are not that big, 8-ish nodes. Maybe the custom instance type (`custom-10-11264`) causes problems?

Comment: That sounds like it likely triggers a resize of the master. I don't know if there is any documentation about it

Comment: I too am facing the same issue. I have set both AutoRepair and AutoUpgrade to false. Still the `Repairing cluster` operation happens when I do a `helm install`. I have created a couple of node pools. As a result, our CI systems fail, as these operations take more than 15-20 minutes. I wish there was an easy way to disable this.

Comment: I'm using terraform to create my cluster and setting auto repair / auto upgrade to false works ok https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_node_pool.html

Comment: @AndreasJansson have you solved the issue?

Comment: @KoopaKiller sadly not

Comment: @AndreasJansson What is the Kubernetes version you are using on GKE? And what is the size of your cluster?

Comment: @KoopaKiller thank you for your help! I'm actually not working on this project anymore, so I've shut down the cluster. I never managed to solve it, but the cluster had around 20 nodes and 100 services.

Comment: Do you remember which version of Kubernetes you used ?

Comment: @matt_j I'm working on a different project now, still seeing this issue. Version 1.17.17-gke.3000. Seems to happen after installing stable/redis with Helm, like Sankar mentioned above.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify a larger master initial size?